Charging 18650 Li-ion battery with dynamo
I want to charging 18650 with dynamo. The dynamo will not work regularly, you can think of it as being turned by hand, that is, it will not be able to produce a constant energy. I think this will be a problem when charging 18650 batteries. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do? I think I can solve this problem by using a capacitor, but I can't quite figure it out in my head.

You will need a buck-boost battery charger.  Building one is not a good starter project if you don't have a background in EE, there are commercial versions that can be purchased.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You will need three devices:

A Step-up / step down converter to convert the highly variable voltage from the dynamo to a constant voltage
A Li-ion charger to limit the current and regulate the voltage to levels acceptable by the Li-ion battery
A protector BMS (Battery Management System) to protect the cells in the battery

After reading the above, you should realize that the complexity of this project is such that you would be better off buying a ready-made product instead of attempting to spin your own.


Arms like Popeye.   The energy in an 18650 means that one would have to do a LOT of work to charge a battery.


You do not need to buy a ready-made product. Both the needed buck-boost and the BMS with charging capability are readily available modules you can get and integrate yourself. Not only does this reduce the cost drastically, but it also gives you a lot more flexibility of form factor, supported charging rate, whether you want to support concurrent charge and supply to a load, etc.

you probably need a full bridge rectifier as well, since most give off AC.

@dandavis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo says: "A dynamo is an electrical generator that creates direct current using a commutator." Do people sell alternators but call then "dynamo"?

yes they do, especially smaller ones like for bikes; generator, dynamo, and alternator are all used interchangably, at least here in the midwest us and online. I didn't even realize the distinctions, until now; thanks!
